# I Need Refresh When I First Time Login

Tags: angular, authentication, nestjs, authorization

**When I login, I cannot pass `auth` information to my application without refreshing the page.**

Login service:

```
loginService(auth: Auth): Observable<ResponseModel> {
    return this.apollo
      .mutate<any>({
        mutation: this.LOGIN_USER,
        variables: {
          auth,
        },
      })
      .pipe(
        map((result) => {
          return result.data.login;
        })
      );
  }
```

Login component:

```
login() {
    this.isLoading = true;

    if (this.form.invalid) {
      this._snackBar.open('Lütfen tüm alanları doldurun.', 'Tamam', {
        duration: 3000,
      });
      this.isLoading = false;
      return;
    }

    const auth = {
      email: this.form.value.email,
      password: this.form.value.password,
    };

    this.authService.loginService(auth).subscribe((data) => {
      if (!data.isSuccessful) {
        this._snackBar.open(data.message, 'Tamam', {
          duration: 2000,
        });
        this.isLoading = false;
        return;
      }
      this._snackBar.open(data.message, 'Tamam', {
        duration: 2000,
      });
      localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data.data);

      this.router.navigate(['/']);

      this.isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

Like i said everything is resolved when i refresh the page.

Under normal conditions, when I log in to the site, it needs to get the auth information directly from the `localStorage` and report the authorized information to the API.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, actually I was having this problem because I overlooked something very simple. While logging in, I was only using the click event on the button I was redirecting. The problem was solved when I put a tag in it and made `href='/'`.

Comment: Irfan, just a little remark use routerLink instead of href; routerLink  is the attribute provided by angular to navigate to different components without reloading the page.